# How to stop function in event handler

Tags: javascript

I wanna just hide [jsPanel](http://jspanel.de/) window instead of remove DOM when click [X] icon.

jsPanel support [jspanelbeforeclose](http://jspanel.de/api/event/jspanelclosed) event.

### My thought

1. Observe `jspanelbeforeclose` event and stop further action.
2. When click [x] icon of jsPanel, it will trigger `jspanelbeforeclose` event.

I think if step 1 is stopped, step 2 function `panel.remove()` will not be executed.

My question is how to stop 1 correctly? (Or how to prevent execute `panel.remove()`)

I already test below methods, but both not work.

> e.stopPropagation();
>
> e.preventDefault();
>
> return false;

jsPanel code snippet

```
// closes a jsPanel and removes it from the DOM
close: function (panel) {
    ...
    panel.trigger('jspanelbeforeclose', panelID);
   
    ...
    // remove the jsPanel itself
    panel.remove();

    ...
});
```

My code

```
$('body').on('jspanelbeforeclose', function(event, id) {
// HOW TO DO
});
```

Comment: Your current reasoning won't work, since the event is created by the close event, not the other way around.

Comment: The `close` method does't provide for a way for the `jspanelbeforeclose` event to stop the closing. You need to catch the event that causes the close (if there is one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a far easier method. If you want the close button to hide the panel instead of closing it, why don't you just assign another handler to the close button of this panel like

```
var myPanel = $.jsPanel({
  // your panel config ...
  callback: function (panel) {
    // in the callback get the close button
    $('.jsPanel-btn-close', panel)
    // remove the standard handler
    .off()
    // and assign one that hides the panel
    .on('click', function(){
      panel.hide();
    });
  }
});
```

Whenever you need the panel back just call

```
myPanel.show();
```

Comment: Ah,  I forgot the callback option, thank you for your rapid answer. thank you very much.